# Click table rows to send parameters to a new Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to make every tr clickable so that it redirects to a URL with issue_id as a parameter.
I have searched a lot and seen many examples of jquery and javascript but still can't reach to a solution. I am facing this maybe because it's a dynamic table.

This is my table:

```
<table border-bottom=1 align=center style="text-align:center" class="myTable" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Priority</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Date</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Issue ID</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(3)">Issue Subject</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(4)">Name</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(5)">Location</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(6)">Feedback</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(7)">Status</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(8)">Department</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% while(rs1.next()){ %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="priority" id="priority">
            <option value="<%=rs1.getString(11)%>" selected>
              <%=rs1.getString(11)%>
            </option>
            <option value="low">Low</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="high">High</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%=rs1.getString(14) %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%=rs1.getString(1) %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%=rs1.getString(2) %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%=rs1.getString(6) %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%=rs1.getString(4) %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%=rs1.getString(9) %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%=rs1.getString(7) %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="dept" id="dept">
            <option value="<%=rs1.getString(10)%>" selected<%=rs1.getString(10)%></option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
            <option value="health">Health</option>
            <option value="education">Education</option>
            <option value="sports">Sports</option>
            <option value="welfare">Welfare</option>
            <option value="forest">Forest</option>
            <option value="food">Food</option>
            <option value="agriculture">Agriculture</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
      </tr>
      <%}%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're using the id="dept" multiple times, but ids have to be unique. Either use classes or increment the name of the ids.

Comment: sorry for that.. I changed it

Answer (score 0):

If you have jquery already, you can write something like

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', (evt) => {
  // read url from evt.target
  // redirect to url
});
```

this way it doesnt matter when/where your tr-s are coming from. it probably worths to restrict the `tr` with some parent id/class

Comment: probably also needs to handle that select he has in there. otherwise clicking the select will bubble up to your on click event of the tr

Comment: yes, i meant something similar with restrictions with class/attribute

Comment: I'm a big fan of the html5 data attributes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes just put the relevant data as data attributes on the row. and then on click event you have access to everything without trying to parse it out of the tds

Comment: Heyy @BryanDellinger can you give an example. Take a simplier table.. It would be easy for me to understand.

Comment: $(".myTable").on("click", "td", function(){
                                        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                                        var issueid = $tr.find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
                                        window.location = 'viewIssues.jsp?issue_id='+issueid;

                                });

Comment: ^^^   This is working but how do I disable select columns

Comment: @mayukhsroy if this resolves your problem, please set my post as the answer.

Comment: @TamasKuzdi sure bro.. But can u tell me how to I not include select columns because its bubbling the on click event